jquery Event keypress not picked up by spline.3d embed
Goal: I want to make my 3D-embed react to a j-query simulated keypress.
Setup: I have a spline.3d embed in my website and in spline I set up a visible reaction for pressing the zero (0) key on the keyboard. When I press the zero key on my keyboard, it works just fine. Now I want to trigger the same effect, by simulating that keypress with java script or jquery and bind it to a element-hover on the website.
Problem: The effect is not triggered by my code. Can you guys help me where my thinking is wrong?
code:
(1) I used the following jquery to emit/imitate the keypress of the zero key:
// Add event listener when DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Add mouseover event to elements with class "hoverx"
    $('.hoverx').mouseover(function() {
      // Create and trigger a keypress event for '0' key
      $(document).trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {
        key: '0',
        keyCode: 48, // ASCII code for '0' key
        which: 48, // ASCII code for '0' key
        code: 'Digit0',
        charCode: 48 // ASCII code for '0' key
      }));
    });
  });

(2) Setup on website (jQuery is included in webflow, where I built my website):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dokument</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav> </nav>
    <section>
          <div>
              <div data-spline-url="https://prod.spline.design/gWaLjgmepcVMzPkW/scene.splinecode">
                  <canvas width="1640" height="817" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                  </canvas>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div>
              <div>
                  <div>
                    <div class="hoverx">
                      <h6>TEXT</h6>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>


Your code is right, but simulating key presses like this doesn't cause the browser to perform any actions that would normally be triggered by physically pressing the key. For example, triggering an Enter key press event on a form input won't cause the form to submit. You have to find where the highlight thing is done in your current code and do the same to obtain also the hover effect.

@FernandoDelCantão Ok. So I would have to analyze the spline3d code and find out how it does communicate my key 0 press? Or should I try to find out what a browser does when I press 0-key?
